# Ember Route Query Params

Tags: ember.js

i would like to open a new perspective with query params.

That means in my index.hbs i click a button get the value from the input field.
After that i will open a new route in my case map-view with path '/map'  with query params like

```
localhost:4200/map/?search=xyz
```

when i do in my index controller:

```
queryparams:['location'],
location:null,
```

and in my route

```
  actions:{
    search(location){
      this.transitionTo('map-view');
  }
}
```

i get on my index url instantly

```
/?location=xcyxyx
```

but i want on my map route

```
localhost:4200/map/?search=xyz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `search` property in `index.js` controller, use it for `queryParams` value  transitioning to `map-view` route.

index.hbs

```
{{input value=search}}
<br />
<button {{action 'transitionToLocation'}}> Search</button>
```

controllers/index.js   - refer [`transitionToRoute`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  search:'india',
  actions:{
    transitionToLocation(){
      this.transitionToRoute('map-view',{queryParams: {search: this.get('search')}});
    }
  }
});
```

**routes/map-view.js**
 Define queryParams `search` with refreshModel true then this will force to fire `beforeModel` and `model` and `afterModel` hook for `search` property change.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams:{search: {refreshModel:true}},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The queryparam is going to be 'search' since that is what you want showing in your URL.

The syntax can be found on:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/query-params/

Further down on that page, it shows how to specify query parameters when using transitionTo.  Hope this helps.